# Averaging cells in one column based on date of another column in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, average

I have searched high and low on the internet and still can't find a solution to what seems to be a simple issue so I am here hoping someone will enlighten me.

I have a table(not pivot) in Excel 2010 and I need a formula that will calculate the average of a group of cells in column B based on the date in column A and display it in column C but only on the first line of the date(s).
Columns A and B are static. Only column C needs a formula.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Here is what I want the table to look like when calculated:

[image: Desired Results]

Comment: Did you try `AVERAGEIFS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - using a helper pivot table**

You can first use the data in Column A and B to make a pivot table such as the following, suppose the pivot table is located in Column F and G, change the value field settings of **Sys** to summarise the value filed by **Average**  :

[image: Pivot Table]

Then in cell `C3`, enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=IF(A3=A2,"",VLOOKUP(A3,F:G,2,0))
```

[image: Solution1]

---

**Solution 2 - using array formula**

In cell `A3`, enter the following formula and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finish, then drag the formula down:

```
=IF(A3=A2,"",AVERAGE(IFERROR(List_Sys/(List_Date=A3),"")))
```

[image: Solution2]

Answer (score 1):

Find attached :D I used Averageif function, and if to verify if any change in date. then just scrolled down.

***Screenshot:***
[image]

Comment: Put formula as text.

Comment: Thanks! With a little tweaking to fit my worksheet, it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Try following formula-

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$3:$A3,A3)=1,AVERAGEIF($A$3:$A$19,A3,$B$3:$B$19),"")
```

[image]